# How can I test (locally) hosted restful api on a separate machine

Tags: c#, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

I created a RESTFul API using Web API.

I published it locally on my machine in IIS and verified that its up and running.

When I verified my API I would enter http://localhost:{port}/api/{controller}

How could I test this API off another machine (that is in the same network)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace localhost with the machine's IP address or hostname.